# Apache Phoenix java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a tiny Hadoop cluster with 5 data nodes and 1 name node, all 4 core/4 thread machines with 4GB of RAM each, except one data node that has 8GB of RAM.

They're all running RHEL 6 x86_64. HBase version is 1.2 and Phoenix version is 4.14

I am connecting to Apache Phoenix through the Phoenix Query Server and the "thin" JDBC client. Phoenix Query Server is running on the name node.

I am trying to upsert ~2000 tuples, ~25 columns each 10min, the table has over 2 million tuples inserted already, but sometimes I get exceptions in the form:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread 
>   [...] Caused by: AvaticaClientRuntimeException: Remote driver error: RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.execute.CommitException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread -> CommitException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread -> RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread -> OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. Error -1 (00000) null

Phoenix Query Server is running on the name node, I'm not sure what is wrong.

It isn't an actual OutOfMemoryException but as if it were creating many threads and running out of them?

I've tried doing a ps aux and I can't see the Phoenix Query Server process creating more than ~50 threads, which afaik, is way, way less than the thread limit in a normal Linux install.

Maybe it *really* is running out of memory and failing to create native threads is a symptom?

Comment: Side note, `ps aux` will only show processes, not threads.  Try `ps -eLf` and you might get an idea of why you're hitting the limit.

Comment: I don't have it at hand but yes, I used a few commands to list the threads and with some line counting I saw it was hitting ~700 threads, still under the 1k limit the user had. I had Ganglia to monitor the cluster and searching the process history I realized it was hitting the 1k limit when doing inserts at certain point of time. Ganglia showed the cluster reaching the 1k limit multiple times, and then a sudden drop when it stopped due exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the user the Hadoop process was running had too low limits for new processes, I edited

> /etc/security/limits.conf

With:

```
user - nproc 32768
```

And it worked. I did not see a specific thread count limit, but increasing the process count limit did the trick.

I've also read around that increasing the open file count limit is needed for clusters too:

```
 user - nofile 32768
```

I set it up that way to avoid issues in the future.